# Why Does Android 4.0.1 Show The Menu Button With android:targetSdkVersion="11"?

Tags: android, menu

Using android:targetSdkVersion="11", I have removed the menu button on Android 3.0, 3.1 and 3.2.  My software has been shipping like this for months.  However, on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.1, the menu button is present (across multiple apps).  I can't figure out why, unless there is a new requirement for removing the menu button.

I haven't seen whatever this new requirement is posted anywhere, so I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set target sdk to 14 or 15. I believe it will make the menu button disapear.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the case. I have no idea why I'd need to set the target version higher than 11 to say "I don't want the menu button to show up". It looks like I have to rev my apps with every OS update just to remove this stupid button.

Comment: Here is the full answer. http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Basically, Google didn't trust that I knew what I was doing when I set TargetVersion="11", so they have a convoluted rule set to force me to API 14, which I can't do yet because of some required NDK rules that come with setting TargetVersion="14". Thanks Google for not trusting me.